# Como posso gerar um report em php que não é uma tabela?

Tags: php, postgresql, relatório

Eu preciso de criar um *report*/formulário a partir de um `query` em `php`.
Tenho uma base de dados de sócios de um clube de atividades de tempos livres.
A partir desta `query`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT utilizador.nome, utilizador.data_nascimento,
                utilizador.nif, morada.rua,morada.numero_porta, morada.andar,
                morada.codigo_postal1, morada.codigo_postal2, 
                morada.localidade, socio.numero_socio

FROM socioonix, utilizador, morada
WHERE socio.idutilizador = utilizador.idutilizador
AND socio.aprovado = 'Pendente'
AND utilizador.idmorada = morada.idmorada
order by utilizador.nome asc;
```

Esta `query` devolve uma tabela de sócios que estão no estado pendente.

Porém, o que eu quero fazer é criar para cada sócio algo do gênero:

"**nome do sócio**" com o "**nif"** residente em "**morada**" com o "**número de sócio**" está autorizado a frequentar o Clube.

assinaturas dos encarregados de educação

É possível, como?
Peço desculpa se for uma pergunta muito noob, mas os meus conhecimentos só vão até gerar queries e imprimir tabelas.

Comment: Pra começar recomendo que use essa biblioteca, ela supre suas necessidades:

Comment: Pra começar recomendo que use essa biblioteca, ela supre suas necessidades:

https://github.com/geekcom/phpjasper